# Designing SQLite table for Elements that have custom numbers of custom fields

Tags: javascript, sqlite, prisma, redwoodjs

I have an interesting situation where I'm working with posts. I don't know how the user will want to structure the posts. It would either be one block of text, or structured in an a-> b -> c structure where a, b, and c are all text blocks, and if represented as a table, there would be an unknown number of columns and unknown number of rows.

Outside of the post data, there is the possibility of adding custom attributes to the post. Most of these would be shorter text strings, but an unknown number of them.

Understanding that a json object would probably be the simplest solution, I have to fit this into a self-serving db. SQLite seems to be the current accepted solution for Redwoodjs, the framework I'm building out of.  How would I go about storing this kind of data within Redwoodjs using the prisma.js that it comes with?

Edit: The text blocks need to be separate when displaying the post and able to be referenced separately. There is another part of the project that will link to each text block specifically. The user would be choosing how many columns there are before entering any posts (configured in settings), but the rows would have to be updated dynamically. Closest example I can think of is like a test management software where you have precondition, execution steps, and expected results across the top for columns, and each additional step is a row.

Comment: Could you clarify the text block requirement? Are the multiple blocks of text a purely visual consideration (like an html table) or does the data for each text block need to be stored in separate records inside a table? Finally, does the user choose rows and columns in advance or can it be updated dynamically? 

A visual example of what you're talking about might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two routes that you could take. If possible use a NoSQL database, such as [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), which [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb) has support for. There you would be able to create a JSON like structure with as many or as little paragraphs you would like.

If that is not possible a workaround, since [SQLite does not support JSON data](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/sqlite), you could store the stringified JSON data in a text field, and then parse it. This is not the optimal solution, so if possible use the first one.

Comment: AFAIK SQLite does support [JSON](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html), it's just the PRISMA SQLite Connector does not support it (yet): see [prisma#3618](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3786)